# \pgfplothandlerrecord vs. \def

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't understand the purpose and utility of the `\pgfplothandlerrecord{〈macro〉}` command. It is described as follows (p. 1078):

> When this handler is installed, each time a plot stream command is called, this command will be appended to `〈macro〉`. Thus, at the end of the stream, `〈macro〉` will contain all the commands that were issued on the stream. You can then install another handler and invoke `〈macro〉` to “replay” the stream (possibly many times).

The manual proceed to give a code listing as an example. I have added to this listing what's necessary to render it a complete LaTeX manuscript.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{plothandlers}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfplothandlerrecord{\mystream}
  \pgfplotstreamstart
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}
  \pgfplotstreamend

  \pgfplothandlerlineto
  \mystream

  \pgfplothandlerclosedcurve
  \mystream

  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting image is (not to scale):

[image: A PGF plot]

It looks to me as though the code snippet

```
\pgfplothandlerrecord{<macro>}
\pgfplotstreamstart
...
\pgfplotstreamend
```

is the same as

```
\def<macro>{%
\pgfplotstreamstart
...
\pgfplotstreamend}
```

This impression is, in this case, borne out empirically.

What are the differences between the two? Since the `def` version is a little more succinct, and doesn't require the user to learn a new command, I can't help but wonder: what are the advantages of this plot handler over a plain `def`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handler will record *only* the stream commands. Other commands inside the stream it will be ignored. You get a sort of cleaned up code. In your example it doesn't matter as there is nothing else. But it is easy to write some example where it can make a difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{plothandlers}
\begin{document}
\newlength\mylength
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfplothandlerrecord{\mystreamA}

  \pgfplotstreamstart
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
  \newcommand\blub{abc}
  \setlength\mylength{2cm}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{\mylength}{1cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}
  \pgfplotstreamend


  \pgfplothandlerlineto
  \mystreamA

  \setlength\mylength{4cm}
  \pgfplothandlerclosedcurve
  \mystreamA

  \pgfusepath{stroke}


\end{pgfpicture}


\begin{pgfpicture}  
  \def\mystreamB{%
  \pgfplotstreamstart
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
  %\newcommand\blub{abc} %error
  \setlength\mylength{2cm}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{\mylength}{1cm}}
  \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}
  \pgfplotstreamend
  }

  \pgfplothandlerlineto
  \mystreamB
  \setlength\mylength{4cm}
  \pgfplothandlerclosedcurve
  \mystreamB

  \pgfusepath{stroke}

\end{pgfpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]